# Can I apply for a new Schengen visa after previously overstaying?

Tags: schengen, overstaying, business-travel, malta

I arrived in Italy on a Schengen visa and overstayed in France for three months but no biometric was taken. Is it possible to apply to any other Schengen countries with a new passport?  Now I want to go to Malta on a business visa. Will there be a chance of rejection?

Comment: What happened when you left Schengen? You say no biometric was taken, but were you questioned about having overstayed your visa? Was a record of your exit taken (e.g. by scanning your passport at the border, or by providing passport details to your travel company)?

Answer (score 5):

- If they realize that you are the same person who overstayed before, your application will probably be rejected. There is no certainty.
- If your new passport has the same personal data as the old one, there is a possibility that they realize you are the same person.

So yes, there is a chance of rejection. It depends on the contents of various government databases which we do not know.